# Editing custom fields for comments

Tags: custom-field, comments, comment-meta

I need help with why the save function is not working in the edit_comment hook.

Here is the code for the 'comment_post' hook:

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_data' );
function save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
    if ( ( isset( $_POST['private'] ) ) && ( $_POST['private'] != '') )
    $private = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['private']);
    add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'private', $private );
}
```

And here is the 'edit_comment' hook:

```
add_action( 'edit_comment', 'extend_comment_edit_metafields' );
function extend_comment_edit_metafields( $comment_id ) {
    if( ! isset( $_POST['extend_comment_update'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['extend_comment_update'], 'extend_comment_update' ) ) return;
        if ( ( isset( $_POST['private'] ) ) && ( $_POST['private'] != '') ) :
        $private = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['private']);
        update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'private', $private );
        else :
        delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'private', $private );
        endif;
}
```

This adds a checkmark box in the edit window to make the comment private.

The checkmark box appears but it does not save when I update the comment in the edit window. Any idea why?

Comment: This is not the full code, is it? I mean, I cannot replicate your problem only with what you published...

Comment: Is `private` a **checkbox** or a **text field**? You seem to be conflating the data types in your whitelisting code.

Comment: @ChipBennett - I'm basing this off a tutorial so you may be right. I don't think I need this: wp_filter_nohtml_kses. Also, I don't think I need wp_nonce_field (verified by $_POST['extend_comment_update']. I think these two verification techniques are used for string inputs and can be left out for checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've way over-complicated things. Assuming `private` is a checkbox, just check for it being set, and act accordingly. With form `$_POST` data, a checkbox will send its value if checked, and will send *nothing* if not checked:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['private'] ) ) {
    update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'private', 'private' );
} else {
    delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'private', 'private' );
}
```

Note that, since a checkbox is binary (checked/unchecked), you can hard-code the value into your `update_comment_meta()` call, thereby inherently sanitizing the user input.